# getRuntime Android show process

Tags: android, shell, process

I'm doing a simple app that show the currently process in android, like a shell.

My app execute ls, cd, makedir and other commands, but top or htop command doesnt. (htop doesn't recognize, and top, the app freeze). I need root to this? I've downloaded the terminal app in unrooted android and top command works.

my app has 2 class. a principal and a shell

principal class

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ShellExecuter exe = new ShellExecuter();
            command = input.getText().toString();

            String outp = exe.Executer(command);
            out.setText(outp);
            Log.d("Output", outp);
        }
```

shell class

```
public String Executer(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";           
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String response = output.toString();
        return response;

    }
```

Why some commands the app works and top for example doesn't??

Answer (score 0):

If you have your Device connected, go to the shell to see what commands you have available using the following command in your computer's command line:

> adb shell

At first glance you will be able to tell that "top" is a job that "displays and update sorted information about processes" and it blocks the shell commands line, hence, in your application is locking the thread that executed that command.

Hope it Helps!

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

thanks. adb shell with top command show the process

but

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top");
```

doesn't maybe works??

I don't understante cause my app freeze

or a top -n 1 not fixed?